# passing what my mouse over is to function - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip

I'm new to javascript so i'm not exactly sure how I can do this. Basically, in my website I have a kind of tooltip, that displays when hovering over certain input boxes.
This is my javascript:

```
function showTip () {
    firstnameTip.style.display = "inline";
}
function hideTip () {
    firstnameTip.style.display = "none";
}
/* link HTML elements to corresponding event function */
function init () {
    /* link the variables to the HTML elements */
    firstnameTip = document.getElementById("firstnameTip");
    firstname = document.getElementById("firstname");
    /* assigns functions to corresponding events */
    firstname.onmouseover = showTip; /* for mouse */
    firstname.onmouseout = hideTip;
    firstname.onfocus = showTip; /* for cursor on input field */
    firstname.onblur = hideTip; /* for cursor moving out */
}
/* execute the initialisation function once the window*/
window.onload = init;
```

Basically the functionality i would like is to if i hover over "firstname", it displays the firstnameTip, and so on for other things like lastname (lastnameTip), etc.

Simple question but I've tried many things and can't figure it out. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I'd set it up:

```
function showTip (tipElement) {
    return function () {
        tipElement.style.display = "inline";
    };
}

function hideTip (element, tipElement) {
    return function () {
        if (document.activeElement !== element) {
            tipElement.style.display = "none";
        }
    };
}

function init() {
    initTipEvents("firstname", "firstnameTip");
    initTipEvents("lastname", "lastnameTip");
}

function initTipEvents(elementId, tipId) {
    var el = document.getElementById(elementId),
        tip = document.getElementById(tipId),
        showHandler = showTip(tip),
        hideHandler = hideTip(el, tip);

    el.onmouseover = showHandler;
    el.onfocus = showHandler;

    el.onmouseout = hideHandler;
    el.onblur = hideHandler;
}

window.onload = init;
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LX2Cb/

The `initTipEvents` binds all necessary events, based on an element's `id` and its tip's `id`, reusing the modified `showTip` and `hideTip` functions. I added an extra check to the `hideTip` function to make sure that the tip isn't hidden when the mouse leaves the input, yet its still focused.

Answer (score 0):

And whats the problem? Works like a charm:

```
var firstnameTip;
var firstname;

function showTip () {
    firstnameTip.style.display = "inline";
}
function hideTip () {
    firstnameTip.style.display = "none";
}
/* link HTML elements to corresponding event function */
function init () {
    /* link the variables to the HTML elements */
    firstnameTip = document.getElementById("firstnameTip");
    firstname = document.getElementById("firstname");
    /* assigns functions to corresponding events */
    firstname.onmouseover = showTip; /* for mouse */
    firstname.onmouseout = hideTip;
    firstname.onfocus = showTip; /* for cursor on input field */
    firstname.onblur = hideTip; /* for cursor moving out */
}
/* execute the initialisation function once the window*/
init();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6QvXT/

Comment: This isn't applied to **multiple** elements like the OP requested, and would be very long if you had to do all that for every element

Answer (score 0):

ok, to have that more generic, you should use the event parameter passed to the handler and the retrieve the target object out of that like:

```
var getTarget = function (event)
{
    var ttn = null;
    if (!event) 
        event = window.event;
    else if (event.target) 
        ttn = event.target;
    else if (event.srcElement) 
        ttn = event.srcElement;

    var tipId = ttn.id + "Tip";
    ttn = document.getElementById(tipId);
    return ttn;
}
```

and then:

```
function showTip (evt) {
    var ttn = getTarget(evt);
    ttn.style.display = "inline";
}

function hideTip (evt) {
    var ttn = getTarget(evt);
    ttn.style.display = "none";
}
```

furthermore:

```
function init () {

    /* for all relevant elements */
    for ( .... ) // iterate through a list or the dom
    {
        var theElement = ....(); // get the element

        /* assigns functions to corresponding events */
        theElement.onmouseover = showTip; /* for mouse */
        theElement.onmouseout = hideTip;
        theElement.onfocus = showTip; /* for cursor on input field */
        theElement.onblur = hideTip; /* for cursor moving out */
     }
}
/* execute the initialisation function once the window*/
init();
```

hope that helps.